# How to accelerate the cpu's uptime?

Tags: java, cpu

There is a JDK bug: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8022628

It will get java.net.SocketTimeoutException in 49.7 days.

In that link, it says "we've accelerated the cpu's uptime". I want make a test for the bug, but I don't know how to "accelerate the cpu's uptime".

---

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;

public class TestSocket
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5555);
        serverSocket.accept();
    }
}
```

I ran the program above, than changed the time to 49.7 days later, or even more later, but there's no SocketTimeoutException.

JDK version:
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: What do you think that means?

Comment: Why do you want to test a Java bug? Test your own code, not the platform.

Comment: @EJP Yes, I need to test my own code. I want to know whether my code is affected by this bug. But I'm not sure setting the clock forward is the same with actually waiting 49.7 days.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it means just set the clock forward. Timers are usually based on the clock, so moving the clock forward makes timers expire sooner.

This is why, incidentally, [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) avoids abrupt clock adjustments: it can cause aberrations in programs with timers. It strongly prefers to perform slow, gradual adjustments over a period of time.